# scikit learn label encoding prints as row instead of column

Tags: scikit-learn, label-encoding

I am trying to do label encoding using sci kit learn's built in function but why does my result print as row instead of an additional column?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# creating instance of labelencoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
# Assigning numerical values and storing in another column
y_data['coded_sklearn'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(y_data['coded_sklearn'])

print(y_data)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrUcc.png)

Comment: Did you create a `Data-Frame` before doing this step @odebear?

Comment: @YScharf 
I loaded in a csv file and used below codes to get the y_data

```
y_col_name = 'Class'
y_data = data[y_col_name]
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `y_data['coded_sklearn'] = labelencoder.fit_transform(y_data['numeric'])` ? With `numeric` representing the `column name` of the label-data in the `Data-Frame`?